# By using ejb 3 , jsf and jboss is it possible to call an EJB method from web module?

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0, session-bean

Even if I have different modules in my Java EE application including myproject-web and myproject-ejb; is it possible to call (or inject) my ejb session bean which is in the ejb module from a managed bean which is in the web module?
When I asked before, I see the following declaration:

```
@EJB private BeanInterface yourbean
```

However, I wanna learn that whether it is possible or not, to call each other between different contexts (one of it in ejb context, the other one -managed bean- is in web context)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out that it is impossible without writing your own resolver by now.. Thanks

Comment: Bariscan, Could you describe your solution?

Comment: I could not find a solution yet, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject an `@EJB` in a `@ManagedBean` class, but not the other way round. If you'd like to execute the desired business logic in the EJB class, then you have to pass the managed bean instance as method argument yourselves.

```
@Stateless
public class EJB {
    public void process(ManagedBean bean) {
        // Business logic.
    }
}

@ManagedBean
public class ManagedBean {
    @EJB private EJB ejb;

    public void submit() {
        ejb.process(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but I'd be cautious with passing the whole managed bean to the EJB. You can effectively be passing a proxy, which might be irrelevant in an EJB context. + it would most likely be a violation of "the law of Demeter"

Comment: At first, many thanks for your replies.
So, do you mean that I dont have to do jndi lookup to find the ejb session which is in ejb context from a web module?
I know if the ejb and managed bean are in the same context, same module (like myProject-ejb) it is possible to inject with @EJB anno. However, I could not find out whether it is possible to inject from different contexts...
Do you have any idea about that?

Many thanks,
Baris

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this by all means, i guess you could try to write your own property resolver and inject by yourself(I didn't try).